# ¿Guardar primitiva de OpenGl en ArrayList?

Tags: c#, opengl

Quería saber si es posible guardar las primitivas de OpenGl (GL_Lines,GL_Points,GL_Triangles etc...) en un `ArrayList`. Es decir que cada "hueco"
del `Array` contenga los datos de la primitiva que se ha creado (coordenadas,color,etc). De esta manera poder recorrerlo para ver que primitivas se han utilizado.
Si es posible querría saber como se hace en C# y sino cual es la alternativa para poder conseguir esto.

Comment: Creo que necesitamos algo mas de contexto. Si no me equivoco, para usar OpenGl en C# necesitas alguna libreria que haga de wrapper. Esa información sería importante. Por otro lado, Arraylist no debe usarse en C#, sino `List<T>`. Por ultimo, no conozco opengl, pero podrías crear una clase que pudiera contener los datos que necesitas de cada primitiva, almacenarlos en tu List y luego recorerrlo.

Comment: @Pikoh lo siento pero no sé que es un wrapper...

Comment: Un wrapper es una libreria que expone clases .net de otro libreria que no es de .net,como opengl que es c++, como por ejemplo Opentk